# WLM reports "side-by-side configuration is incorrect"?

Tags: windows-vista, windows-live-messenger

My Windows Live Messenger was working fine 15 days ago.

But since then when I open it, I saw a following error message:

> The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event log for more detail.

I am using Windows Vista Service Pack 2

Comment: @Fronezfire: Your question has been migrated to a more appropriate community, feel free to link your account here so you can provide more information. In specific: Can you provide us with the specific events from the application log that for more information? Have you tried reinstalling Windows Live?

Answer (score 1):

Install Microsoft Visual C++ package.

Read more on http://msghelp.net/showthread.php?tid=79697

And if that doesn't help, you can delete Windows Live Messenger config files from `%AppData%`.